# Angular UI progressbar with gradient (from 0% to 100%)

Tags: css, angularjs, html, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm attempting to use a gradient on my Angular UI `progressbar` using the following HTML and CSS:

`<progressbar max="100" value="67"></progressbar>`

```
.progress-bar {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, green, red);
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that the gradient goes from 0 to 67% (in this case), rather than the desired 0 to 100%. How can I set the gradient to always be from 0 to 100% while stopping the progress bar at whatever `value` is set to?